# Set Lucene IndexWriter max fields

Tags: lucene

I was started working my way through the second edition of 'Lucene in Action' which uses the 3.0 API, the author creates a basic INdexWriter with the following method

```
private IndexWriter getIndexWriter() throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException {
     return new IndexWriter(directory, new WhitespaceAnalyzer(), IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.Unlimited);
    }
```

In the code Below I've made the changes according the current API, with the exception that I cannot figure out how to set the writer's max field length to unlimited like the constant in the book example. I've just inserted the int 1000 below. Is this unlimited constant just gone completely in the current API?

```
private IndexWriter getIndexWriter() throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException {
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, 
                new LimitTokenCountAnalyzer(new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36), 1000));  
        return new IndexWriter(directory, iwc);
    }
```

Thanks, this is just for curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexWriter` javadoc says:

> @deprecated use `LimitTokenCountAnalyzer` instead. Note that the
>   behvaior slightly changed - the analyzer limits the number of
>   tokens per token stream created, while this setting limits the
>   total number of tokens to index. This only matters if you index
>   many multi-valued fields though.

So, in other words, a hard-wired method has been replaced with a nice adapter/delegate pattern.